# How to use the 3d convolution in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution

I am not sure, how to use the conv3d in tf: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv3d

I want to have a kernel size of `[depth, height, widht]=[3,3,3]`, that convoles over my input tensor that as a `shape [1,21,1,6,7]` and ought to have an output `shape of [1,19,4,5] = [batch,channels,height,width]`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1,21,4,5])
input_pad = tf.pad(input, [[0,0], [0,0], [1,1], [1,1]], 'CONSTANT')
x = tf.expand_dims(input_pad, axis=2) #[1,21,1,6,7]
print ("(batch, channels, depth, height, width) ", x)

t_conv1_act = tf.layers.conv3d(
    # inputs=x, filters=19, kernel_size=[1,3,3], #depth,height,width
    inputs=x, filters=21, kernel_size=[3,3,3], # todo does not work
    padding='valid', data_format='channels_first',
)
with tf.Session() as sess: 
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    init_l = tf.local_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init_op)
    sess.run(init_l)

    tmp = np.ones((1,21,4,5))
    output = sess.run(t_conv1_act, feed_dict={input: tmp})
    print "y: ", output, output.shape
```

but  I get this error:

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'conv3d/Conv3D' (op: 'Conv3D') with input shapes: [1,21,1,6,7], [3,3,3,21,19].
```

I am not sure about the parameters `depth` and `filters` and I guess that I mix something up.

Comment: I suspect the error is in `expand_dims`, because it gives `[1,21,1,6,7]`, but you actually want `[1,1,21,6,7]` (i.e. add a channel axis just after the batch axis)

Comment: Yes, I think, you are right!

Comment: @BlackBear can u write an answer so that I can close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the error is in `expand_dims`, because it gives `[1,21,1,6,7]`, but you actually want `[1,1,21,6,7]` (i.e. add a channel axis just after the batch axis)